# Problems with codeigniter on ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I’ve got Codeigniter on Ubuntu 10 (LAMP). I have an htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dort
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php
#controller, previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dort/index.php?/$1 [L]
#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends
#the request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dort/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Up until now, we connected the remote server with an IP address,my base site is sitting under a folder called 
‘dort’, so we used to call it like this: http://some_ip/dort

now we mapped a virtual host to dort, so we call it like: http://demo.dort.com/ and suddenly nothing

works except for the login page (index.php). I’ve changed $config[‘base_url’] in config.php but i

keep getting 404.

Please help :(

Answer (score 7):

Did you use virtual host?

I have same problem and solve with this

1) Make virtual host in my case is like this: file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@email.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dort
    ServerName yourdomain.biz #this domain must be define tld info.
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_2.log
    <Directory /var/www/dort>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

2) Setting host in file /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   yourdomain.biz
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

3) `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Send admin URL's to the admin controller (then skips the rest of the redirect rules)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin(.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/admin/$1 [L]    

    # Redirects any request thats not a file or directory through to the main controller
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/main/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

4) Make sure when restart apache not show error

```
 Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

5) Go to browse and run this url http://yourdomain.biz

Answer (score 4):

Above solution worked for me. I just want to highlight one thing. Make sure you have **AllowOverride All** instead **AllowOverride None** in virtual host file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default