# 404 Page Not Found.The page you requested was not found in ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu-15.10

I fall in problem that I do not understand.I have been working in windows on codeigniter for 5months. Now I chose to ubuntu platform.I have a project named test that I put in my webroot. If I run it in windows it works but same thing doesn't work in ubuntu.

It shows 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.I checked my config file and it is OK.
this is the url `http://localhost/test/index.php/test_con`.
and I also checked codeigniter is installed successfully in ubuntu.

Whenever I write this url `http://localhost/test` it shows welcome message of codeigniter.

Now my question is to u guys, is there any other conventions to run codeigniter in ubuntu.

Comment: is PHP set up in your Ubuntu install?

Comment: You need to configure your **Apache Virtual Host** (in case you are using Apache)

Comment: @gabe3886 I installed xampp.so there must be php

Comment: Does xampp have mod_rewrite enabled for apache?

Comment: mod_rewrite is need to enable if u want to remove the index.php in your url.right??now i need not to remove index.php from url.

Comment: How have you named the file and class of controller example Welcome.php and class Welcome extends CI_Controller {} you need to make sure that the class and file name has first letter upper case.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 If I didn't make the class name first letter upper case it shouldn't work in windows as well.same thing runs on windows bt it doesn't work on ubuntu.

Comment: @hmamun, When it comes to the first letter being upper case it will work on a WAMP stack but not on a LAMP stack. Perhaps is shouldn't work on Windows but it does. It won't on Linux. (Been there, done that.)

Comment: Found this link here may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082745/problems-with-codeigniter-on-ubuntu